# Why recycle view inside horizontal scroll view not working?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have created calendar by using recycle view. It worked perfectly in emulator but in real device only few elements gets loaded.

I used horizontal scrollview so all elements load at once and I'm adding padding at both sides for animations.

Code Snippet:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/dateHSV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dateRV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/rv_item_calender" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

### In Mobile

[image: In My Device]

### In Emulator (android 6)

[image: Emulator]

As You can see in mobile only 3 dates gets loaded while in emulator (android 6) all dates gets loaded.

Comment: Add your code snippet for better clarification.

Comment: And, you didn't say where you are getting error. Is it here `It worked perfectly in emulator but in real device only few elements gets loaded.` Try to add further information. Check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)